# Drupal: collapse CCK Fields in edit content pages?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-fapi, drupal-alter

can I collapse the field in my edit-content page in Drupal ?

For example, at the bottom of the page Revision Information, URL Path Settings, Authoring Information etc are collapsed.

I would like to have this functionality for the CCK Fields as well.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `hook_form_alter` by putting the fields into a fieldset the you make collapsible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the CCK Fieldgroup module to create a fieldgroup in the same interface you create new fields. Go to the fieldgroup settings page to make it collapsed by default. Then drag-n-drop fields to be under a given fieldgroup.

Fieldgroup is part of the CCK project, just turn it on in the modules page.

Using `hook_form_alter()` is a cleaner solution but technically a bit more difficult.

Comment: So what you suggest, is to use the field group as wrapper, and add the item inside it so I can collapse it.

Comment: The CCK Fieldgroup is essentially a GUI version of using hook_form_alter(). A fieldgroup is manifested in the Forms API as a fieldset, and the collapsed fieldset properties from the Fieldgroup configuration are pushed into the fieldset definition as well.